# Is dollar-quoting in Postgres enough to escape malicious inputs?

Tags: postgresql, security, dollar-quoting

Is dollar quoting enough to prevent malicious inputs like SQL injection?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE title = $secret$ hack'-- $secret$
```

where user input is

```
hack'--
```

Answer (score 1):

No, of course not, because the hacker could enter a string containing `$secret$`.

What you suggest goes by the name “security by obscurity” and enjoys ill respect among security experts. For example, it would not work at all with open source software.

Fortunately PostgreSQL and all relevant APIs have functions that make the safe construction of SQL statements simple.

Comment: Well, the "secret" would be a generated password stored in an environment variable in a server. Could you guide or link "functions that make the safe construction of SQL statements simple"?

Comment: Even if the risk is low, why not play it safe? Each API has its own functions. If you want to use database functions to safely construct an SQL string, use [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).